# How to link/pair HTML 5 with a hardware device?

Tags: ios, html, websocket, hardware, atmel

I have two entities which I would like to be able to start a communication:

- Hardware Device Using Atmel ATSAMS70 and WINC1500 Wifi Module
- HTML 5 App

The idea to have a HTML 5 app is to be able to communicate easily with most of the commercial devices like: Windows computers, Android Phones, Mac OSX computer and iOS devices. Apart from that, I would avoid working with native code at all.

Currently, they can talk with each other using WebSockets but somehow the IP address of the custom board has to be known from HTML 5 to initiate the communication.

In order to do this, I can think of 3 options:

1. Using WebRTC I can get the local IP address of the browser and then I could do  a scan of the local devices considering a 255.255.255.0 network mask.
2. Have an external server that the hardware device can send its local address which will be later retrieved by HTML 5.
3. Using Bonjour or some sort of device discovery service between the board and HTML5.

I could not find a way to achieve #3 but #2 seems feasible to me. #1 is what I am doing now, but WebRTC is currently not supported on iOS.

So, is there any other better possibility to achieve this communication?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention how the WINC1500 unit is being connected to the network but presumably this is in STA mode (acting as a wifi station rather than becoming a software access point or part of an ad-hoc network) and is being provided with its IP details through an existing access point?

Ordinarily I'd suggest that once connected, the device ought to start indicating its availability on the network via a regular UDP broadcast on a specific port but my (admittedly limited) understanding of WebSockets it is that it creates TCP connections.  The only implementation of Bonjour that I've seen uses UDP messaging too, that may be why you've had trouble with your third approach.

Your second approach seems more likely to work well.  A server at a known (or discoverable) IP on the local network which allows the Atmel device to register itself (and its IP address) and also allows other applications (your HTML 5 WebSockets applications) to request that connection information to allow them to create the WebSocket TCP connections they need.

I suppose that doesn't really answer your question as to "Is there a better way?", other than to say "Not that I can think of, your second approach looks good to me...".  Sorry!  Sounds like a very interesting project, overall,